# SQL database (Django) - Relate all records in table B to each record in table A

Tags: mysql, django, database

I'm working in Django, but this question could apply to any database in general.

In my models, I have a UserProfile table. Another table UserQA contains a field for question_text and a field for question_answer. The problem with this model is that I would need a ManyToMany relation that has the overhead of two longints per question, and the question_text is duplicated for each user.

Basically, the requirements are:

1. Table of questions which users can contribute to by adding their own questions
2. Store 1 character answer (Y/N/O/Null) to each question for every user

*2.1 Is there a way to extend this if I want some questions to have more complex answers?*

This seemed like an easy problem, but I can't figure it out... The way I thought of doing it seems very inefficient, is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need another model, can be `Question`. The final result would be something like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(...)

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(...)

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer = models.CharField(...)
```

If you want more complicated answers, like especific values, lists of values, you can create one more model:

```
class QuestionAlternative(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    value = models.CharField(...)
```

And then redefine `UserAnswer`:

```
class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(QuestionAlternative)
```

With this, you will have the `Questions` in one place, one `UserAnswer` per question, and the `QuestionAlternative`s how many times they must exist. Does not worry about the `ForeignKey` fields, they are not overheads and they build beautiful, reusable structures.

Comment: Thanks the first part makes sense to me now. I'm still confused about 'QuestionAlternative', how does it store the new choices? For example, if the two different answers I want are:

`models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('O','Other'),('M','Male'),('F','Female')`
 and 
`models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('Y','Yes'),('N','No'),('O','Other')`

How would I enter those choices?

Comment: Oh I see, every choice (yes/no/male/female/other) would be stored in `QuestionAlternative`, and then linked by primary key so `UserAnswer` can select 3 of them, right? I think I got it now, thank you very much Jean Jung!

Comment: Sorry for the triple post, one more thing I just noticed - if I understand `ForeignKey` correctly, the `answer = models.ForeignKey(QuestionAlternative)` would be related to only one answer. Many different questions could be related to that same answer. Should it be using `ManyToManyField` instead?

Comment: Nevermind, I just remembered that users only get one answer, so ForeignKey would be best. I think I finally understand this now lol, thanks again :D